# How to display JSON data from API server in TextView and EditText in Android?

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit2

I am trying to get the value of a JSON response and display it in my textView and editText. But I get a **null object reference** as an error.

**JSON Response:**

```
{
    "srNo": 1,
    "date": "11/14/2019 12:00:00 AM",
    "fieldEngineer": "Angel",
    "accountName": "Forever 21 Megamall",
    "irNo": 1,
    "joNo": 1,
    "address": "Mandaluyong City",
    "contactPerson": "Jansen Babon",
    "designation": "",
    "contactNo": "",
    "email": "",
    "timeIn": "00:00:00",
    "timeOut": "00:00:00",
    "productType": "Security",
    "problem": ""
}
```

**Java class:**

```
    private void fetchData() {
        JsonObject paramObject = new JsonObject();


        Call<ResObj> call = userService.userLogin(paramObject);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResObj>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResObj> call, retrofit2.Response<ResObj> response) {



               ResObj resObj = response.body();

               String srNo = resObj.getSrNo();
               String date = resObj.getDate();
               String fieldEngineer = resObj.getFieldEngineer();
               String accountName = resObj.getAccountName();
               String irNo = resObj.getIrNo();
               String joNo = resObj.getJoNo();
               String address = resObj.getAddress();
               String contactPerson = resObj.getContactPerson();
               String designation = resObj.getDesignation();
               String contactNo = resObj.getContactNo();
               String email = resObj.getEmail();
               String timeIn = resObj.getTimeIn();
               String timeOut = resObj.getTimeOut();
               String productType = resObj.getProductType();
               String problem = resObj.getProblem();

               //the response I am getting here is null

               tvSrNo.setText(srNo);
               etdate.setText(date);
               etfieldengineer.setText(fieldEngineer);
               etaccname.setText(accountName);
               etirno.setText(irNo);
               etjono.setText(joNo);

                JsonObject workObj = new JsonObject();

                try {
                    workObj.addProperty("srNo", resObj.getSrNo());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResObj> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

I tried using this  `tvSrNo.setText(resObj.getSrNo())` instead of `tvSrNo.setText(srNo)` but it still gets the same problem.

I am also using Retrofit.

I expect the result that JSON data will be placed in an editText or textView. But apparently, the response is getting null.

**ResObj class:**

```
    private String date;
    private String address;
    private String accountName;
    private String contactPerson;
    private String timeOut;
    private String problem;
    private String srNo;
    private String fieldEngineer;
    private String joNo;
    private String irNo;
    private String message;
    private String designation;
    private String email;
    private String timeIn;
    private String productType;
    private boolean status;
    private String contactNo;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }


    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }

    public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }

    public String getContactPerson() {
        return contactPerson;
    }

    public void setContactPerson(String contactPerson) {
        this.contactPerson = contactPerson;
    }

    public String getTimeOut() {
        return timeOut;
    }

    public void setTimeOut(String timeOut) {
        this.timeOut = timeOut;
    }

    public String getProblem() {
        return problem;
    }

    public void setProblem(String problem) {
        this.problem = problem;
    }

    public String getSrNo() {
        return srNo;
    }

    public void setSrNo(String srNo) {
        this.srNo = srNo;
    }

    public String getFieldEngineer() {
        return fieldEngineer;
    }

    public void setFieldEngineer(String fieldEngineer) {
        this.fieldEngineer = fieldEngineer;
    }

    public String getJoNo() {
        return joNo;
    }

    public void setJoNo(String joNo) {
        this.joNo = joNo;
    }

    public String getIrNo() {
        return irNo;
    }

    public void setIrNo(String irNo) {
        this.irNo = irNo;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getTimeIn() {
        return timeIn;
    }

    public void setTimeIn(String timeIn) {
        this.timeIn = timeIn;
    }

    public String getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }

    public void setProductType(String productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }

    public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }
```

**Logcat:**

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.android.ras.ResObj.getSrNo()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.android.ras.MainActivity$3.onResponse(MainActivity.java:187)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Comment: can you show us your POJO / getter and setter file?

Comment: probably View is null, add crash logs for more info

Comment: put a log in the response and check you are getting a perfect response or not.

Comment: @VinayJayaram i edited my post. Thanks!

Comment: share logcat...

Comment: @ShivamOberoi edited my post. Thanks!

Comment: Issuse is with the String, Change  private String srNo to int. Also change the same in setter and getter

Comment: @VinayJayaram still shows the same error.

Comment: Try make your `ResObj` a data class. Remove all setters and getters and make fields public. But my instinct here is that the returned body is null. Did you debug? can you log the `response.body()`?

Comment: `if(response.isSuccessful()){ //get values}` check if your response is not `null`.

Comment: Can you show how you build your Retrofit instance ? Double check you are using a deserializer in it (e.g. `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`)

Comment: `    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String url){
        if (retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }` @ArthurAttout

Comment: @DevendraSingh tried it. but it still returns null.

Comment: Problem is here. `ResObj resObj = response.body();` `response.body()` is giving null. Check your API is live and giving proper response in postman first.

Comment: @NaitikSoni it works perfectly in postman.

Comment: Is your response have ResObj `json node`. I guess it is not parsing. you have to change your response type as json or add `ResObj` as root node.

Comment: Just debug it and check "response.body();" is null or not if its null then there is problem in API calling.

Answer (score 0):

Change your String to Integer

```
 public class Codebeautify {
     private Integer srNo;
     private String date;
     private String fieldEngineer;
     private String accountName;
     private Integer irNo;
     private Integer joNo;
     private String address;
     private String contactPerson;
     private String designation;
     private String contactNo;
     private String email;
     private String timeIn;
     private String timeOut;
     private String productType;
     private String problem;


     // Getter Methods 

     public Integer getSrNo() {
      return srNo;
     }

     public String getDate() {
      return date;
     }

     public String getFieldEngineer() {
      return fieldEngineer;
     }

     public String getAccountName() {
      return accountName;
     }

     public Integer getIrNo() {
      return irNo;
     }

     public  Integer getJoNo() {
      return joNo;
     }

     public String getAddress() {
      return address;
     }

     public String getContactPerson() {
      return contactPerson;
     }

     public String getDesignation() {
      return designation;
     }

     public String getContactNo() {
      return contactNo;
     }

     public String getEmail() {
      return email;
     }

     public String getTimeIn() {
      return timeIn;
     }

     public String getTimeOut() {
      return timeOut;
     }

     public String getProductType() {
      return productType;
     }

     public String getProblem() {
      return problem;
     }

     // Setter Methods 

     public void setSrNo(Integer srNo) {
      this.srNo = srNo;
     }

     public void setDate(String date) {
      this.date = date;
     }

     public void setFieldEngineer(String fieldEngineer) {
      this.fieldEngineer = fieldEngineer;
     }

     public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
      this.accountName = accountName;
     }

     public void setIrNo(Integer irNo) {
      this.irNo = irNo;
     }

     public void setJoNo(Integer joNo) {
      this.joNo = joNo;
     }

     public void setAddress(String address) {
      this.address = address;
     }

     public void setContactPerson(String contactPerson) {
      this.contactPerson = contactPerson;
     }

     public void setDesignation(String designation) {
      this.designation = designation;
     }

     public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
      this.contactNo = contactNo;
     }

     public void setEmail(String email) {
      this.email = email;
     }

     public void setTimeIn(String timeIn) {
      this.timeIn = timeIn;
     }

     public void setTimeOut(String timeOut) {
      this.timeOut = timeOut;
     }

     public void setProductType(String productType) {
      this.productType = productType;
     }

     public void setProblem(String problem) {
      this.problem = problem;
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your POJO class like this

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("srNo")
@Expose
private Integer srNo;
@SerializedName("date")
@Expose
private String date;
@SerializedName("fieldEngineer")
@Expose
private String fieldEngineer;
@SerializedName("accountName")
@Expose
private String accountName;
@SerializedName("irNo")
@Expose
private Integer irNo;
@SerializedName("joNo")
@Expose
private Integer joNo;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private String address;
@SerializedName("contactPerson")
@Expose
private String contactPerson;
@SerializedName("designation")
@Expose
private String designation;
@SerializedName("contactNo")
@Expose
private String contactNo;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("timeIn")
@Expose
private String timeIn;
@SerializedName("timeOut")
@Expose
private String timeOut;
@SerializedName("productType")
@Expose
private String productType;
@SerializedName("problem")
@Expose
private String problem;

public Integer getSrNo() {
return srNo;
}

public void setSrNo(Integer srNo) {
this.srNo = srNo;
}

public String getDate() {
return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
this.date = date;
}

public String getFieldEngineer() {
return fieldEngineer;
}

public void setFieldEngineer(String fieldEngineer) {
this.fieldEngineer = fieldEngineer;
}

public String getAccountName() {
return accountName;
}

public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
this.accountName = accountName;
}

public Integer getIrNo() {
return irNo;
}

public void setIrNo(Integer irNo) {
this.irNo = irNo;
}

public Integer getJoNo() {
return joNo;
}

public void setJoNo(Integer joNo) {
this.joNo = joNo;
}

public String getAddress() {
return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
this.address = address;
}

public String getContactPerson() {
return contactPerson;
}

public void setContactPerson(String contactPerson) {
this.contactPerson = contactPerson;
}

public String getDesignation() {
return designation;
}

public void setDesignation(String designation) {
this.designation = designation;
}

public String getContactNo() {
return contactNo;
}

public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
this.contactNo = contactNo;
}

public String getEmail() {
return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}

public String getTimeIn() {
return timeIn;
}

public void setTimeIn(String timeIn) {
this.timeIn = timeIn;
}

public String getTimeOut() {
return timeOut;
}

public void setTimeOut(String timeOut) {
this.timeOut = timeOut;
}

public String getProductType() {
return productType;
}

public void setProductType(String productType) {
this.productType = productType;
}

public String getProblem() {
return problem;
}

public void setProblem(String problem) {
this.problem = problem;
}

}
```

make sure to have Gson Converter in your retrofit instance

```
private static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
```

then make call and put the data in ArrayList

Comment: @NaitikSoni it still didn't work. It still gets the same error.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.android.ras.ResObj.getSrNo()' on a null object reference

**Note: NullPointerException because you did not declare SrNo inside the model class**

Try to use a jason to java class generator:

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

**Source type: JSON**
**Annotation style: Gson( if you used GSON) or none**
**Include getters and setters**

```
public class Example {

private Integer srNo;
private String date;
private String fieldEngineer;
private String accountName;
private Integer irNo;
private Integer joNo;
private String address;
private String contactPerson;
private String designation;
private String contactNo;
private String email;
private String timeIn;
private String timeOut;
private String productType;
private String problem;

public Integer getSrNo() {
return srNo;
}

public void setSrNo(Integer srNo) {
this.srNo = srNo;
}

public String getDate() {
return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
this.date = date;
}

public String getFieldEngineer() {
return fieldEngineer;
}

public void setFieldEngineer(String fieldEngineer) {
this.fieldEngineer = fieldEngineer;
}

public String getAccountName() {
return accountName;
}

public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
this.accountName = accountName;
}

public Integer getIrNo() {
return irNo;
}

public void setIrNo(Integer irNo) {
this.irNo = irNo;
}

public Integer getJoNo() {
return joNo;
}

public void setJoNo(Integer joNo) {
this.joNo = joNo;
}

public String getAddress() {
return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
this.address = address;
}

public String getContactPerson() {
return contactPerson;
}

public void setContactPerson(String contactPerson) {
this.contactPerson = contactPerson;
}

public String getDesignation() {
return designation;
}

public void setDesignation(String designation) {
this.designation = designation;
}

public String getContactNo() {
return contactNo;
}

public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
this.contactNo = contactNo;
}

public String getEmail() {
return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}

public String getTimeIn() {
return timeIn;
}

public void setTimeIn(String timeIn) {
this.timeIn = timeIn;
}

public String getTimeOut() {
return timeOut;
}

public void setTimeOut(String timeOut) {
this.timeOut = timeOut;
}

public String getProductType() {
return productType;
}

public void setProductType(String productType) {
this.productType = productType;
}

public String getProblem() {
return problem;
}

public void setProblem(String problem) {
this.problem = problem;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

first : Check response output,
you can Log.i or Toast it,,,
If your response not load or null ... - (the Problem in here)

Second : if respon Ok, Check your ResObj.getSrNo().
Print again... check 
String srNo = resObj.getSrNo();
Log.i srNo... (problem or not)

Or checkyour Class Codebeautify

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonObject paramObject = new JsonObject();

Call<ResObj> call = userService.userLogin(paramObject); // paramObject is empty object
```

You are passing empty `JsonObject` to your API parameter.

So you have to add parameter value to your `paramObject`. like this

```
try {
     JsonObject paramObject = new JsonObject();
     paramObject.addProperty("mobile", mobile);
     // add other properties if you have

} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

after that you should call your api like

```
Call<ResObj> call = userService.userLogin(paramObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

As i am seeing the problem is in parsing, The retrofit can not mapping as your response is n't having `ResObj` as root.

```
{ "ResObj": { "srNo": 1, "date": "11/14/201912: 00: 00AM", "fieldEngineer": "Angel", "accountName": "Forever21Megamall", "irNo": 1, "joNo": 1, "address": "MandaluyongCity", "contactPerson": "JansenBabon", "designation": "", "contactNo": "", "email": "", "timeIn": "00: 00: 00", "timeOut": "00: 00: 00", "productType": "Security", "problem": "" } }
```

Modify your response or change your request

```
Call<JSONObject> call = userService.userLogin(paramObject);
```

Later in extract the values manually.